# codeigniter recursive model function returning blank but when printing it in the model showing properly

Tags: recursion, codeigniter-2

codeigniter recursive model function  returning blank but when printing it in the model showing properly

here is my code,

for controller

> $commision_arr=$this->billing_model->root_commision($category_manager['id']);

and in the model

> public    function root_commision($id)
>    {
>
> ```
>    $sql="SELECT * FROM tbl_mst_category WHERE id  = '".$id."'"; 
>    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
>    $row=$query->row_array();
>    if($row['parent']!=0)
>    {
>       $this->root_commision($row['parent']);
>    }
>    else       
>       return  $row;
> ```
>
> }

Answer (score 0):

recursion is tricky huh?

i think the problem is that you were only returning the id for the deepest element, but not returning that to the calling method -- so it would only work for the case where the parent id was called.  i can't test the code below, but it should point you in the right direction.  NB, it returns the row as an object, not as an array as your code does.

On a more academic note, if the table is large it may be better to pre-calculate these root ids for each of these categories.  it will make the query much faster -- recursion is not fast.  look at [transitive closures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_closure)

```
public function root_commision($id,$root_found = FALSE)
{

    // returns FALSE if the id is not found, or the parent row.
    $query = $this->db->get_where('tbl_mst_category', array('id' => $id));
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0 )
    {
        $row = $query->first_row();
        if (($row->parent ) != 0 )
        {
            return $this->root_commision($row_id);
        }
        else
        {
            return $row;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> you have to return function at the calling time then only you can get
>   the value of recursive function just add "return" keyword before function call.

```
public function root_commision($id)
{

   $sql="SELECT * FROM tbl_mst_category WHERE id  = '".$id."'"; 
   $query = $this->db->query($sql);
   $row=$query->row_array();
   if($row['parent']!=0)
   {
      return $this->root_commision($row['parent']);
   }
   else       
      return  $row;   

}
```